# Is it possible to register an object dynamically created by myself in runtime as a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I need to use Spring AOP facility and would not like to make AspectJ integration in order to intercept a method call to an object which is not initially a spring bean. The object is going to be created dynamically in runtime . It's not possible for me to add a bean definition into `ApplicationContext` configuration file. So does spring provide such a facility?

Comment: What if you create prototype scope bean holder where you can set the newly created object? Do you need exactly bean?

Comment: No... Spring can only apply AOP to Spring beans. Yuo can register a singleton but that will not be proxied. Why wouldn't it be possible to add the bean to the spring context, define it prototype scoped and use the `BeanFactory` as a factory to create the bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, because the class is just a Java class not dericlty related to DAOs, Services and QuartzScheduler stuffs which we ususally define within the context. I thought mixing in such classes in the app-context is not a good idea. All I want is to intercept a method call and do some stuff. Is AspectJ going to be neccesary?

Comment: If you don't want it registered that is your only option. But why not simply register it and use the context as a factory. YOu could create your own factory which wraps the `BeanFactory` or `ApplicationContext` so that you limit the amount of Spring dependencies in your code. Is a lot easier then trying to introduce load or compile time weaving into your code.

Comment: M. Deinum is right. You have to go one way: the Spring way with Spring AOP or the POJO way with AspectJ. You cannot take a shower without getting wet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. You could create a prototype scoped bean with `@Bean` and `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` in a `@Configuration` bean, which would act as a factory:

```
@Configuration
public class Factory {

    public static class A {

        private final int x;

        public A(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Autowired
    public A getA(int arg) {
        try {
            return A.class.getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(arg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanCreationException("A" + arg, "Could not create instance of bean A", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public int getArg() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {

        int r1 = this.getArg();
        A a1 = this.getA(r1);
        System.out.println("a1.x = " + a1.x); // 1 or 2

        int r2 = this.getArg();
        A a2 = this.getA(r2);
        System.out.println("a2.x = " + a2.x); // 2 or 1, different to a1.x
    }
}
```

In method `getA()`, I could have created an instance of the `A` bean just with `new A(arg)`, however I created it dynamically, so that it's closer to your use case.

Note that from Spring 4.x version onwards, you can use `@Autowired` to autowire the parameters of the bean to be returned by a `@Bean` method, meaning that those parameters can be other beans, even of primitive types. That's why I made the argument of the `A` bean to also be a prototype scoped bean.

Then in the `@PostConstruct` method (which I'm using as a test), I get two instances of the `int` argument and two instances of the `A` bean, and assign each one of them to each instance of `A`.

If I hadn't used the `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` annotation, both `getArg()` and `getA(arg)` `@Bean` methods would have returned the same instance when invoked for the second time, as Spring's default scope for beans is `ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON`. If this is the behavior you expect, just remove the `@Scope` annotations.